# Java executing only last part of if condition

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm a java beginner. I am facing the code issue below.

I'm setting the remarks and returning the response, but I only get the remarks printed as **Date is invalid** for all the iterations. if i pass all inputs as empty it has to print just **ID is empty** but it prints **Date is invalid** all the time

```
    public Response getInfoDetails(RequestDetails request)
     {
      Response response = new Response();
      if(Utils.isEmpty(request.getID()))
      {
       response.setREMARKS("ID is empty);
      }

      if(Utils.isEmpty(request.getName()))
      {
       response.setREMARKS("Name is empty);
      }
      if(Utils.isIpAddressValid(request.getIP()))
      {
       response.setREMARKS("IP is invalid");
      }
      if(Utils.isDateValid(request.getDate()))
      {
       response.setREMARKS("Date is invalid");
      }
       return response;
     }
```

please advise

Comment: That depends on the code of `Utils.isDateValid`. Also, you probably intended your last condition to be `if(!Utils.isDateValid(request.getDate()))`

Comment: Please indent your code to make it readable. And clarify your question: you're talking about iterations and things being printed, but the code has no loop, and never prints anything.

Comment: Is date also invalid?

Comment: Use `if` with `else` and think again about the `true` and `false` values of the `Utils` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've figured out what the problem is - you want to stop and return.

You can do something like this:

```
if (Utils.isIpAddressValid(request.getIP()))
{
    response.setREMARKS("IP is invalid");
    return response; // don't proceed - stop and return
}
```

You could also use `if..else`, but **I** find it too verbose and less readable.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `if .. else` if you want some code to be executed only if condition is false.

Answer (score 1):

There can be two solutions : 
You should return response if it enters any of the if statement. It wont move to next statement.

OR

Use else if statement as mentioned by BobTheBuilder

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a logic error in your code

```
if(Utils.isDateValid(request.getDate()))
{
  response.setREMARKS("Date is invalid");
}
```

adds the remark that the date is invalid if the date is valid. The check should probably be

```
if(!Utils.isDateValid(request.getDate()))
{
  response.setREMARKS("Date is invalid");
}
```

And the same goes for the IP address check.